# Need count of searched files in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to take the count of an object's elements.
My code:

```
$myfiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator ( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));   
$array[] = $myfiles;

echo'<font size="4" style="font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Files Found:   </font>';
echo'<font size="4" style="font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">';
foreach($array as $f)
    {               
        $c[] = $f;
        echo count($c);
    }
 echo'</font>';
 echo '<hr>';
```

This code outputs the result as, for the 4 elements the count is shown as 1.

Could any please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: `font` tag? seriously?

Comment: calculate the count() outside the loop.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Pranay, can you post the code of RecursiveDirectoryIterator?  That would help us help you.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @Rachael It is a PHP iterator ([RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. If you want to count files using these iterators then you can do so like this:

```
// Create a recursive directory iterator which skips
// the current and parent directories (i.e. "." and "..")
$rDirIter = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

// Create an iterator for the recursive iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rDirIter);

// Counter used to count how many files there are
$count = 0;

// Iterate over all the files in the iterator
foreach ($files as $file) {

    // Uncomment to see files...
    //var_dump((string) $file);

    // Increment counter for each encountered file
    $count++;
}
// Echo the count
echo $count;
```

You should take a look at the documentation for the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator) iterators.